# Determine the acceleration given the position function of a particle

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> The position function of a particle in a test laboratory is $s(t) = \frac{10t}
> {t^2+3}$.
>   Determine the acceleration of the particle of particle after 4 seconds.

The speed $v(t)$ of the particle is the derivative of the position $\frac{ds(t)}{dt}$.

I got $v(t) = \frac{10(-t^2+3)}{(t^2+3)^2}$

For the acceleration $a(t)$ I tried taking the derivative of $v(t)$ but got the wrong answer at $a(4)$.

$$a(t)=\frac{-2t\cdot (t^3+3)^2-10(-t^2+3)\cdot 2(t^2+3)\cdot(2t)}{(t^2+3)^4}$$

Comment: is that $s(t) = \frac{10t}{t^2+3}$?

Comment: that should be $-20t$ at the beginning of your expression for $a(t)$

Comment: quotient rule is death

Comment: @DougM Is that the only mistake for $a(t)$? Even with $-20t$ I am not getting $560/6859$

Comment: I am.  You can cancel a $(t^2 + 3)$ from each term leaving $\frac {-20t\cdot(t^2+3) - 10(-t^2+3)(4t)}{(t^2+3)^3} = \frac {-80(19) -10(-13)(16)}{19^3} = \frac {560}{6859}$

Comment: Ok it was a calculation error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S(t)$ be given by

$$s(t)=\frac{10t}{t^2+3}\tag1$$

Differentiating $(1)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
v(t)&=s'(t)\\\\
&=-10\frac{t^2-3}{(t^2+3)^2}\\\\
&=-10\frac{t^2+3-6}{(t^2+3)^2}\\\\
&=-10\frac{1}{t^2+3}+60\frac{1}{(t^2+3)^2}\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Differentiating $(2)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
a(t)&=s''(t)\\\\
&=20\frac{t}{(t^2+3)^2}-240\frac{t}{(t^2+3)^3}\\\\
&=\frac{20t(t^2-9)}{(t^2+3)^3}\tag 3
\end{align}$$

Evaluting $(3)$ at $t=4$, we find that

$$a(4)=\frac{560}{6859}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark

Comment: Is it easier to derivative a function in it's expanded form? I don't understand how you got $a(t)$ in one step from the expanded $v(t)$

Comment: Well, there are actually two steps.  And I do think it's easier in this case to work with the form of $v(t)$ in $(2)$.  Thank you for accepting this answer!

Answer (score 1):

$$s(t) = \frac{10t}{t^2+3}$$

$$\implies v(t) = \frac{ds}{dt} = \frac{(t^2+3)\cdot 10 - 10t\cdot 2t}{(t^2+3)^2} $$

$$v(t) = \frac{10t^2+30-20t^2}{(t^2+3)^2} = \frac{30-10t^2}{(t^2+3)^2}$$

$$\implies a(t) = \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{(t^2+3)^2\cdot -20t -(30-10t^2)\cdot 2(t^2+3)\cdot 2t}{(t^2+3)^4}$$

$$a(t) = \frac{-20t(t^2+3)+4t(10t^2-30)}{(t^2+3)^3}$$

$$\implies a(4) = \frac{-80\cdot 19 +16\cdot 130}{19^3} = \frac{560}{6859}$$